# QGIS 2.0 Plug In Repository - How to Set Parameters to qgis=1.8

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

A number of very useful QGIS plug ins available in 1.8 are not available in 2.0. Is there a way to set the parameter page in "Repository Details" to 1.8 so I can access the 1.8 plug ins and check functionality?

The option is grayed out as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible.  1.8 plugins need to be updated before they will work with 2.0 which is why some are not available.

The best course of action here is:

- Contact the author to see if they have any update plans
- If not, try and contact a developer about updating the plugin
- or update the plugin/s yourself and contribute the changes back

Most authors are doing the update so normally the other steps are not needed.